# Разбивка строки на части PHP

Tags: preg_match, php

Подскажите пожалуйста кто-нибудь как разбить строку, например:
$str = "b1k3ul";
$res = ...какая-то функция которая разбивает на куски по 2 символа...
И чтобы в итоге получилось:
$res[0] = "b1";
$res[1] = "k3";
$res[2] = "ul";

Answer (score 3):

[str_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) Почему, интересно, у вас не получилось её найти?

```
$str = "I'mALooser,Baby";
$res = str_split( $str, 2);
print_r($res);
/* Выводит:
Array
(
    [0] => I'
    [1] => mA
    [2] => Lo
    [3] => os
    [4] => er
    [5] => ,B
    [6] => ab
    [7] => y
)
*/
```

Если строка в UTF8, то каждый символ занимает два байта. В комментариях есть решение для Unicode строк.